# Flutter: How to get permission from user?

Tags: flutter

I want to ask uses permission internet, storage, sms etc. What I am gonna do for it?
Please solution work iOS and Android.
Thanks for any answer.

Comment: You should do your research by yourself before posting on StackOverflow. You could use [this plugin](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler)

Comment: FYI you don't have to ask internet permission from the user.

Comment: My app run and connect internet at emulator but not connect at real device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the package [permission_handler](https://pub.dev/packages/permission_handler) which handles the permission requests and even check the permission's state.
This package works with both IOS and Android and it is easy to implement.